# Java Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

Как подключить Spring MVC к обычному MAVEN проекту?

Comment: Недавно смотрел отличный видеоурок. Да простят меня за рекламу, но на youtube канал devcolibri, с отдельным плейлистом, посвещенным созданию сервера как раз с использованием Spring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подключите спринговые депенденси в `pom.xml`.

```
<!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Сконфигурировать проект. Добавить конфигурационный файл `application-context.xml` в папку `/webapp/WEB-INF/..` 
Подключить файл через project facets. 
Добавить `web.xml` или создать архитип `web-applicaiton` и конф файл в `web.xml`.

Задеплоить.